# Нужно ли везде указывать типы в PHP

Tags: php, ооп, типизация, динамическая-типизация

Стараюсь везде где можно указывать типы, даже там где это очевидно. Хочу понять, влияет ли это как-то на производительность, да и много ли пользы от этого?

Comment: Производительность чуть-чуть проседает. Пользы от этого много. Программа сразу заругается, если вы подсунете ей неправильный аргумент

Comment: Я бы тоже добавил что пользы ОЧЕНЬ много, учитывая что этот язык (был) слаботипизированным. Теперь, со строгими типами, разработчикам будет намного проще выявлять ошибки ещё до запуска кода и контролировать его структуру данных.